# Change the Origin in Git when using TOWER

Tags: git, user-interface, github, gitlab, git-tower

Using the TOWER Git application, it appears impossible to change the ORIGIN.
So how do I change the GIT Origin?

With such a paid application, one would expect it to save all the Terminal activity, at least in regards to its function which it to make Git more visual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very easy to edit the origin in Tower! Simply open the repository in Tower, right-click on your remote (origin) and select "Edit Connection Settings". There, enter the new URL in the Fetch URL field. That's it!

You can find further information on this in Tower's Help documentation: https://www.git-tower.com/help/guides/remote-repositories/connect-authenticate/

Comment: This is something I struggled with, could find the option nore did I find a google solution, so to help others I created this Question, and we place my work around, plus your answer so we can help others. might be a good idea to place all the FAQ from Tower here too.

Comment: Right click does noting when you don't have a remote in the first place. this solution does not work

Answer (score 1):

The only way to change the GIT Repo or Origin is by using command line. The following instructions should help those that struggle.

1. Open Terminal
2. Navigate to the root folder of your project (in settings you can copy the path)
3. cd [paste folder path here]
4. type: git remote -v (This will show the current remote GIT server URLs)
5. type: git remote set-url origin [your git project URL].git (New location now remembered.)
6. Finally type: git pull
   You will be asked for your username and password for the hosted git unless you have set up the public key, but thats another story. And once entered correctly your Tower app should now show the updated remote URL and work using your new credentials.